# Want to show userregister button in jsp if user not exist in sping MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC . I want to show a register button in login page only if user is not registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you stored registered user data somewhere or not, though I assume that you store it to database and try to give this answer, may this will help to you.

First of all pull out all registered user data list from database while login & check whether user login credential is present in this list or not. If present then don't show registered button otherwise show it.